# Rigging Artifacts

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics, motion-capture

I'm playing around with Kinect mocap, I'm completely new to rigging. To get my feet wet, I'm using the resources [here.](https://www.theroyalskies.com/royal-resources) I'm trying to apply the animations from the female base model to the male one. It *basically* works, but has issues:

[image]

When I look at the armature itself, I see that it's incredibly noisy, but somehow the female mesh ignores the jitter and inversions around some bones:

[image]    [image]

I looked at the weight painting on the male mesh and it seems to be OK (note I have no idea what I'm talking about). What should I be looking at here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't find a parameter called "Bone Angle", could you point me to it? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I meant Pole Angle: Select your IK bone in Pose mode, and check the IK constraint, if your bone has a Pole Target it should have a Pole Angle value, try to play with it to see if it fixes your problem

Comment: Neither I nor the original have Pole Target constraints. There are, however, armature constraints on the IK bones. The IK bones are constrained to other bones that are in turn constrained with Copy Location and Copy Rotation to another bone. If I absolutely needed a pole target, the female mesh would also be bugged, no?